# What/where is a WiFiDirectActivity

Tags: android, eclipse

I am attempting to understand and implement the (incomplete) code described in "[Creating P2P Connections with Wi-Fi](http://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html)". This is to add as a separate class to my existing activity. There is a line in the example code as follows:

```
activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
```

but does not show where the variable "activity" came from. Looking for other example code which employs setIsWifiP2pEnabled() I saw [one which declared activity](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java) as follows:

```
private WiFiDirectActivity activity;
```

but if I add that line I get the error `WiFiDirectActivity cannot be resolved to a type`. Eclipse has no suggestions for any imports to add. So I am stuck.

Comment: There is also apparently a [fully complete sample](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/WiFiDirectDemo) for this on GitHub ([pointed out](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39132970/cannot-resolve-symbol-what-is-activity?noredirect=1&lq=1#comment65613163_39132970) by @androidXP).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That file is part of an example project, not a library/jar for you to consume. If you need it for implementing your code, look into that project

See:
https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/WiFiDirectActivity.java

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * A BroadcastReceiver that notifies of important wifi p2p events.
 */
public class WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiP2pManager manager;
    private Channel channel;
    private WiFiDirectActivity activity;

    /**
     * @param manager WifiP2pManager system service
     * @param channel Wifi p2p channel
     * @param activity activity associated with the receiver
     */
    public WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver(WifiP2pManager manager, Channel channel,
            WiFiDirectActivity activity) {
        super();
        this.manager = manager;
        this.channel = channel;
        this.activity = activity;
    }

    /*
     * (non-Javadoc)
     * @see android.content.BroadcastReceiver#onReceive(android.content.Context,
     * android.content.Intent)
     */
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        String action = intent.getAction();
        if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // UI update to indicate wifi p2p status.
            int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
            if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
                // Wifi Direct mode is enabled
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
            } else {
                activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
                activity.resetData();

            }
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P state changed - " + state);
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            // request available peers from the wifi p2p manager. This is an
            // asynchronous call and the calling activity is notified with a
            // callback on PeerListListener.onPeersAvailable()
            if (manager != null) {
                manager.requestPeers(channel, (PeerListListener) activity.getFragmentManager()
                        .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list));
            }
            Log.d(WiFiDirectActivity.TAG, "P2P peers changed");
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

            if (manager == null) {
                return;
            }

            NetworkInfo networkInfo = (NetworkInfo) intent
                    .getParcelableExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_NETWORK_INFO);

            if (networkInfo.isConnected()) {

                // we are connected with the other device, request connection
                // info to find group owner IP

                DeviceDetailFragment fragment = (DeviceDetailFragment) activity
                        .getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.frag_detail);
                manager.requestConnectionInfo(channel, fragment);
            } else {
                // It's a disconnect
                activity.resetData();
            }
        } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
            DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
                    .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
            fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                    WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));

        }
    }
}
```

Here is complete android sdk sample of WIFI Direct at github
[GITHUB](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/WiFiDirectDemo)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/13456884)

Comment: @Soham Update answer