# Cannot resolve symbol: what is activity?

Tags: java, android

I've just started learning how to program android apps.

My intention at the moment is to write an app that allows me to perform p2p communications over WiFi using the tools presented [here](https://developer.android.com/training/connect-devices-wirelessly/wifi-direct.html#receiver).

I am at this point of the tutorial:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    String action = intent.getAction();
    if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        // Determine if Wifi P2P mode is enabled or not, alert
        // the Activity.
        int state = intent.getIntExtra(WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_STATE, -1);
        if (state == WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_STATE_ENABLED) {
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(true);
        } else {
            activity.setIsWifiP2pEnabled(false);
        }
    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_PEERS_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // The peer list has changed!  We should probably do something about
        // that.

    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_CONNECTION_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {

        // Connection state changed!  We should probably do something about
        // that.

    } else if (WifiP2pManager.WIFI_P2P_THIS_DEVICE_CHANGED_ACTION.equals(action)) {
        DeviceListFragment fragment = (DeviceListFragment) activity.getFragmentManager()
                .findFragmentById(R.id.frag_list);
        fragment.updateThisDevice((WifiP2pDevice) intent.getParcelableExtra(
                WifiP2pManager.EXTRA_WIFI_P2P_DEVICE));

    }
}
```

**This is probably a stupid question, but I don't understand what the `activity' symbol is supposed to be. At the moment, Android studio says that it cannot be resolved. I would be very grateful if someone could explain this to me**

Yours sincerely,
An OO beginner.

Comment: It's not a stupid question; it's a somewhat confusing tutorial if you approach it from scratch (or at least, it does not do a great job of highlighting prerequisites). Check out the linked duplicate.

Comment: @JasonC its not duplicate as per you link ,there is difference in activity and broadcast receiver what dave asked is not answered by you link

Comment: @androidXP Sure it is. It is exactly the same question, about exactly the same issue in exactly the same tutorial with the exactly correct answer. The only difference is the OP of the linked question did one extra step of research and found a declaration of `activity` somewhere else, which is not a difference that has any significance for this purpose, other than giving the OP of *this* question a little bonus boost in the right direction. :)

Comment: @JasonC he asked what is activity symbol is you should provide broadcast receiver link 
[BroadCast file](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.java)[link] in comments thn you can mark it as duplicate

Comment: @androidXP Yes. That exact bit of code is already provided in the text of the linked question (I admit, the link was broken, I just fixed it). Did you not see it there? Are you implying that just because some information was in the linked *question* and not just in its *answers* that that information is somehow invisible? Is it possible that I'm putting too much faith in others' ability to read text and infer information from it? I apologize if that was the case. I did not realize that information in questions was invisible.

Comment: that is activity not the same BR where @dave want to be, He might not find what is activity ref there

Comment: @androidXP Well we'll just have to wait and see what DaveS says. If you have info to add feel free to add it clearly in a comment, I am not stopping you at all. :)

Comment: @JasonC i already posted link of BR above as you can also check

Comment: @androidXP You posted the same exact code that was originally in the linked question (*/samples/WiFiDirectDemo/src/com/example/android/wifidirect/WiFiDirectBroadcastReceiver.html*). And I did check, I used your link to update the old broken one, because they were the same. So now you're just confusing everybody by saying that they are different.

Comment: @JasonC Here is link of complete sample from github 
[WIfi Direct Sample](https://github.com/Miserlou/Android-SDK-Samples/tree/master/WiFiDirectDemo)

Comment: @androidXP Now that's the comment you should've just left first before taking up your time and mine, isn't it. :) In fact, why not consider posting that as an answer to the linked question?